# grails uniqueness of constraints

Tags: grails

if I have class `Machine` and class `Car` with property: `Machine machine`,and I want

```
def x = Car(machine1) 
def y = Car(machine1)
```

never to happen, where `machine1` is already existing object of class `Machine`, should I just put in the `Machine` class  properties this:

```
static hasOne = [car: Car]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To re-state you requirements more concisely, it seems you want to ensure that a `Machine` instance can only be owned by a single `Car`. The [Grails docs](http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne) recommend modelling such a relationship like this:

```
class Car {
    static hasOne = [machine: Machine]

    static constraints = {
        machine unique: true
    }
}

class Machine {
    Car car
}
```